# Shell script: How to find what day of the year is today?

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix

How do I tell what year of day is today e.g. if today was Mar 1 2008, it should reply 61.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `%j` format specifier:

```
$ date +%j
016
```

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) says this about `%j`:

> %j
>
> Day of the year as a decimal number [001,366].

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU date,

```
$ date -d "Mar 1 2008" +%j
061
```

If you don't have GNU date, but you have a recent-ish version of Perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -le '
    print Time::Piece->strptime("Mar 1 2008", "%b %e %Y")->strftime("%j")
'
```

Comment: It's not just GNU date. The `%j` specifier is required by POSIX so all compliant implementations must have it.

Comment: You need GNU date for `-d`